# Why am I not getting the right cookies?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, cookies

I'm doing this to get the ID of the current user :

```
int idUser = Convert.ToInt32((HtmlDecode(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["UserCookie"].Values["idUser"])));
```

But sometimes (maybe when server is too busy) I find myself getting the id of another user connected at the same time.

How is this even possible ? It's pretty annoying.

Answer (score 0):

If you are authenticating with different accounts from the same browser, you will have this problem because "multiple browser windows and frames share session cookies". http://windowsitpro.com/windows/q-multiple-instances-internet-explorer-ie-8-or-separate-windows-within-ie-seem-share-cookies. Definitely, your problem has nothing to do with how busy the server is.

Comment: Hello @Razvan, no i'm not trying to authentificating on the same browser. We have 2 computers and if we send a lot of (ajax) requests to the server sometimes I will get my friend's ID and he will get mine...

Comment: Then it'll be helpful to check how this specific cookie is written and used on the server side, because cookies belonging to different sessions can't mix.